# rewrite / redirect url in lighttpd (add a trailing slash )

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, redirect, lighttpd

I need to add a trailing slash (/) to urls in lighttpd. I tested this :

```
url.redirect               = ( "^(.*)$" => "$1/")
```

but this adds a lot of slashes at the end. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell that should only add one slash to the end as you want. Can you give an example of an input, the wrong output this expression gives and a suggestion of what the correct output should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, as Ansari said, you would need something like this.

(Currently, I was doing the same...)

> $SERVER["socket"] == "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx" { url.redirect =
>   ("^(.*[^/])$" => "$1/") }

This would put / in the end of URL.

Answer (score 1):

How about just

```
"^(.*[^/])$" => "$1/"
```

?